# Hashtag in URL not loading correctly

Tags: jquery, hashtag

It is my understanding that using a link like this: http://trinityfel.org/podcast/redesign/downloads/index#truthwalk should load the page with the truthwalk tab selected.

That part is functioning correctly, but from there, things go a little wonky. On the user's first click of one of the "cd covers" the correct series loads, but there is at least one, if not several others listed below it as well. If the user then clicks back on the tab and reclicks the cd cover, it now loads correctly (only showing one series).

Also, as the user clicks around on various tabs after that, the URL retains the # used in the initial link, i.e. navigating to the sermons tab, the URL remains ...index#truthwalk.

I hope this makes sense... I'd really like to solve the issue because otherwise there is no way to link the user directly to the unique tabbed resources, only to the higher level resource library.

This is the code identifying each tab w/ a #

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li><a href="#featured">Featured</a></li>
<li><a href="#sermons">Sermons</a></li>
<li><a href="#truthwalk">TruthWalk</a></li>
<li><a href="#other">Other</a></li>
<li><a href="#print_materials">Print Materials</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the code that ties each tab to the #

```
<div class="panes">
<!-- *** FEATURED TAB ***************************************************** -->
<div id="featured" style="padding-top:10px;">
```

and so on, each the same except for changing the id of the div.

What other code would you need?

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: @Colin well... the code is huge, so the best thing to do would be to visit the page and then view the source code. But I will edit the post to include something that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the jQueryUI Tabs, you could call the following code after the UI has been fully loaded

```
<script>
$(function() { 
    $('.tabs').tabs( "refresh" ); 
}); 
</script>`
```

Comment: Can you explain how exactly `.("refresh")` works? That looks like a syntax error.

Comment: Should be .tabs("refresh"), typo. Assuming you're using the jQueryUI Tabs library then calling the refresh will trigger a refresh of the element.

Comment: That makes more sense. Thanks